# When to use <> and <E> - Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

This is a code fragment from the book **"Data Structures and Algorithms in Java (6th Ed.)"**
This is a sample method for cloning a `SinglyLinkedList` implementation.
To gain a better understanding I'm codeing this up in Eclipse.

I have two questions:

Firstly, in line 3, I get the following warning: Type safety: "Unchecked cast from Object to `SinglyLinkedList<E>`". Why is this?

Secondly, in line 5, why do we have "`new Node<>(`..." and why not use "`new Node<E>(`..."
what's the difference between the two?

```
public SinglyLinkedList<E> clone( ) throws CloneNotSupportedException { 
    //always use inherited Object.clone() to create the initial copy
    SinglyLinkedList<E> other = (SinglyLinkedList<E>) super.clone( ); //<---LINE 3 safecast

    if (size > 0) { // we need independent chain of nodes
        other.head = new Node<>(head.getElement( ), null);//<---LINE 5
        Node<E> walk = head.getNext( ); // walk through remainder of original list
        Node<E> otherTail = other.head; // remember most recently created node

        while (walk != null) { // make a new node storing same element
            Node<E> newest = new Node<>(walk.getElement( ), null);
            otherTail.setNext(newest); // link previous node to this one
            otherTail = newest;
            walk = walk.getNext( );
        } 
    } 
    return other;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 3 :

You are typecasting `super.clone()` which is Object to `SinglyLinkedList<E>`. The warning simply want you to check if `super.clone()` is really instance of `SinglyLinkedList<E>`. You can do this with simple selection:

```
if (super.clone() instanceof SinglyLinkedList<E>)
  SinglyLinkedList<E> other = (SinglyLinkedList<E>) super.clone();
```

Line 5 :

Well you could use `new Node <E>` instead of `new Node<>`. There are no differences. Simply said the compiler already know the type of the generic type you'll instantiate so using the `new Node <E>` is simply redundant. I'm not sure but I think you have to use `new Node <E>` in previous versions of Java (Java 6 and below I think).

Comment: for line 3: why do I need to check if it's really the instance of it? What else would the clone return?

Comment: You don't have to do this. You can add an annotation to ignore the warning, as you know it's safe (and the compiler doesn't, because the compiler doesn't know about the contract of the `clone` method).

Comment: clone() is the default method from Object which is parent of all class in Java. You can't help it. clone() will always return Object.

Comment: @EricMarcelino the `<>` operator was introduced in Java 7. Check the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond

Comment: @YugSingh Nice. Thanks for giving me the link!

Comment: @EricMarcelino The point is that there is no need to do an instanceof check, because it will always be of the same type as the actual class (provided each implementation in the super classes are implemented as by that contract). It is better to suppress the warnung, as @ RealSkeptic pointed out.

Comment: @DorianGray that's true for this case. But in other case, type-casting is very sensitive thing and checking like this will beneficial.

Comment: Yes. I never said anything else.

Answer (score 3):

> Firstly, in line 3, I get the following warning: Type safety: "Unchecked cast from Object to SinglyLinkedList". Why is this?

The method [`clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) returns an `Object` so you have to cast it to `SinglyLinkedList` and the compiler cannot guarantee that such `Object` will be a `SinglyLinkedList`, so you get the warning.
I suggest to read the whole lesson about [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

If you want to hide that warning you can use the following annotation

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SinglyLinkedList<E> clone( ) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
```

> Secondly, in line 5, why do we have "new Node<>(..." and why not use "new Node(..." what's the difference between the two?

Since Java7 you don't need to state the generic type when you invoke the constructor due to 
[Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html).
If you had wrote  `= new Node(head.getElement( ), null);` you would have created a raw type losing the advantages of generics. You would have gotten a warning too.
[JLS - Raw Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) states:

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. **The use of raw types** in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language **is strongly discouraged**. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.

Comment: I think the reason that `compiler cannot guarantee that such Object will be a SinglyLinkedList due to type erasure.` is not correct. I created a custom object and used clone and got the same error as when I converted the custom class to generic. Pls let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @YugSingh You're right. It depends only on `Object.clone()` signature. That method returns an `Object` so you always get the warning.

Answer (score 1):

1)The `clone` Method neetd to return `Object` [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) so any cast is no safe

2)`other.head` already is `<E>` so **you not must** to add `<E>` to the new,the compiler already know the type of the generic type.